# How would we define a topos between Classical Logic and Paraconsistent Logic, and determine what the homomorphism between them would be?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-mathematics, foundations-of-mathematics

How would we define a topos between Classical Logic and Paraconsistent Logic, and determine what the homomorphism between them would be? I learned that topoi can't be used for philosophical ideas, but they can be used for logical systems and other mathematical objects, now I would like to know if these two systems are too different for us to find a homomorphism between the two.

Comment: I voted to close, not because topoi as a grounding for logics isn't fascinating, but because the mechanics are category theory which is a Mathematics StackExchange topic. I suspect most logicians don't have the training to do that sort of advanced category theory.

Comment: "A topos between" makes no sense, topoi are not maps, neither does "the homomorphism between", morphisms are arrows within categories (topoi in particular). The internal logic of a topos is intuitionistic, you cannot stuff paraconsistent logic into it, see [Is there a category whose internal logic is paraconsistent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/476186/152568)

Comment: Here is [nLab's list](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+logic#kinds_of_internal_logics_in_different_categories) of various logics matched to  categories that realize them as internal logics, where those are known.